# Can partial page in Laravel be created with Livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

Suppose if I have a products page, where buyers can ask questions to the seller and the questions are displayed publicly like in Amazon. Can that part alone be made with Laravel Livewire and included in existing blade component?

Comment: Yes it can, but you need to be more precise in your question - include code

Comment: could you provide me with an example? i am still learning laravel

Comment: @DileepP try yourself first, if failed , post your code here, show us how much you tried,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can add livewire component in existing blade file using @livewire('component_name'). If you are using Laravel 7 you can use